# If $-1$is a root for $ax^2+bx−3$, find $a^2+b^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> Given: -1 is a root for $ax^2+bx-3$, with $a,b$ being positive primes, $x\in \Bbb R$.
>
> Find: the numeric value for $a^2+b^2$.

**Background:** question asked in an entrance exam (Colégio Militar 2005).

**My attempt:** the other root is $3/a$ and by substitution we can easily find that $$a-b=3\ \ \text{or}\ \ a^2+b^2-2ab=9.$$
I got stuck at this point... how to get the value for $ab$? Hints please.

Comment: Since `a` and `b` are primes, one solution would be `a = 5` and `b = 2`.

Comment: $a-b=3$ means the difference of $a$ and $b$ is $3$ and if one number is odd, the other one is even, so I don't think you are going to get any further than the suggested $2$ and $5$ since $2$ is the only even prime

Comment: Looks like either a or b is 2 based on a parity argument, since a^2 +b^2 must be odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from $a-b=3$, which is odd, this implies the positive primes cannot be  both odd. So one of them is $2$, the other is an odd prime. As $a-b>0$, it's $b$ which is equal to $2$, so $a=3+b=5$, and $a^2+b^2=29$.

Answer (score 3):

Pure obfuscation.

Nothing about roots or algebra or the sum of $a^2 + b^2$ are relevant.  That $-1$ is a root simply means $a(-1)^2 + b(-1)-3 = 0$ or in other words $a - b =3$ or $a = b+3$.

What *does* matter is that $a,b$ are positive primes and all primes except $2$ are odd. If they were both odd primes then $a -b$ would be an even number.  So one of them is even so one of them is $2$.  So the other is $2+3 = 5$.

So $a^2 + b^2 = 29$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: i assumed they were both odd primes and wounded up with a senseless equation since 3 is not even.  So one of them has to be 2.  Since all positive primes except 2 are greater thab 2 then b has to be 2 which gives a is 5.

That is started like this 
$(2k+1)-(2n+1)=3$

$2(k-n)=3$

Last equation is false. There is no integer $k-n$ that would satisfy that.